# How to make iPhone Share Sheet black?

Tags: iphone, xcode, action

Hi can anyone tell me how I can make the Share Sheet in iOS 6 black? I know how to make Action Sheets black. I use this code for Action Sheet:

```
[actionsheetshare setActionSheetStyle:(UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent)];
```

[image: Black Translucent Action Sheet]

[Eded]
[image: Default]

so does it look by default

Here is my Code I use: `NSString* someText = @"";
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.
    UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[someText]
                                          applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];`

Comment: this is not a `UIActionSheet` it is a `UIActivityViewController` you can use this, which provides similar way..

Comment: I tryed [activityViewController setUIActivityViewController:(UIActivityViewControllerStyleBlackTranslucent)]; but i get an error

Comment: for `UIActivityViewController` by default it is black translucent.. no need to set it..

Comment: @vishy I edited the post to the default screen I get.

Comment: Check your screenshots, when showing status bar (sheet goes black tinted). when showing fullscreen app (sheet goes grey tinted)

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556915/uiactivityviewcontroller-background-color).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set UIStatusBarHidden to 'NO' in your Info.plist. If you have this property set to 'YES', the UIActivityViewController always appears with a grey tint.

I believe that this is a bug and I have filed it as such on Radar (problem #12682274).

Comment: You're right, when showing status Bar the ShareSheet goes black translucent in absence of this (fullscreen app) the ShareSheet will go grey tinted, that's weird. Hope apple give soon an easy way to set custom tint to the object.

Comment: +100 Thanks, this works. I hope there is a different way as I need fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

What code you have written, i just had the below lines.. shows the black translucent, check by using this..

```
NSArray* arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"],@"Hello Guys", nil];
UIActivityViewController* activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:arr applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The whole view is simple UIView with an collection view, you can use its subviews like below to modify as you like

```
activity.view.subviews
```